# Why is my for loop skipping an element in my list?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a list of integers which I am running through a `for`-loop to discover if the sum of two of the elements equals another variable `t`. So if `t` was equal to `10` and I had a list of integers: 
`l = [1,2,3,4,5,8,9]`, then the function should print all the different combinations of numbers `(1,9)`, `(2,8)`.

I feel I am almost there, but something strange happens to the list when I use the `.pop()` function. The code below is being used to show all the combinations of numbers which need to be calculated, but every other element in the list is skipped.

```
l = [1,2,5,8,13,15,26,38]
c = 10
for i in l:
    first = i
    l.pop(0)
    for x in l:
        second = x
        print(first,second)
```

Here is the output:

```
1 2
1 5
1 8
1 13
1 15
1 26
1 38
5 5
5 8
5 13
5 15
5 26
5 38
13 8
13 13
13 15
13 26
13 38
26 13
26 15
26 26
26 38
```

Notice how the `2`, `8`, `15`, and `38` are skipped. 
I am using `l.pop()` so that the second `for`-loop will not use the original value, and the next iteration can then go on to iterate the next element in the list.

Comment: I'm certainly not a Python expert, but I can tell you that in other object oriented languages it's generally considered a pretty bad idea to modify either an iterator or a collection being iterated over from within a loop.  My first suspicion would lie here.  You pop from the list and then try to reference list[1] behind the scenes... but list[1] is now 5, not 2 as you expect, because you have modified the list.

Comment: I think @DavidHoelzer got the right answer.

Comment: @AndrewRushton: That's a rather artificial constraint... You _can_ safely remove elements from a list that you're currently iterating over if you iterate _backwards over the list, although it's safer to iterate over a copy of the list. BTW `.pop(0)` is rather inefficient, since it forces the list to move all the remaining list elements down to fill the gap.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are trying to do will not work, as you are modifying the list while you are iterating it. Say the current "pointer" points to the first element. Now you pop the first, so the pointer is at the second. But when the loop advances, the pointer is moved to the third, and the second is skipped.

It seems you want to find combinations from a list. There are a few other ways you can try:

- Closest to your current approach: Use a `while` loop instead of `for` loop

  ```
  while l:
      first = l.pop(0)
      for second in l:
          print(first, second)
  ```
- Or you could just iterate the indices instead of the lists themselves:

  ```
  for i in range(len(l)):
      for k in range(i+1, len(l)):
          print(l[i], l[k])
  ```
- Or just use `itertools.combinations`

  ```
  import itertools
  for first, second in itertools.combinations(l, 2):
      print(first, second)
  ```

---

However, you can do better than that. Since you are looking for a pair of numbers that adds up to some target number, just subtract the first from the target to get the second and see if that second number is in the list of numbers. Use a `set` to make this lookup happen in constant time, reducing your overall time complexity from O(n²) to O(n).

```
numbers = set([1,2,5,8,13,15,26,38])
target = 10
for first in numbers:
    second = target - first
    if second > first and second in numbers:
        print(first, second)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to choose another approach. You are not permitted to remove elements from the list while iterating over it using a for loop.